# Custom shaped QWidget and setmask

Tags: qt, user-interface, qwidget

I want to create custom shaped qwidget. Im using MDI, and want to create tabshapped widget inside mdiarea (widget would look like tab but have funcionality like window). I draw .png file which I use for masking widget so widget look like I draw, but problem is when im resizing widget, to keep shape Im also resizing QPixmap which generates mask. And cause its still image it degenerates.

Can I somehow correct this?
Or at least to mark area of widget where i want to do masking? (so i can keep degenerating on width only, not width and height).